# React-Bootstrap-Table-Next Search Bar onSearch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I imported SearchBar.js with the following code.
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
I confirmed that the file exists and have this below. I can see the search bar and the clear button on my page but when I try to search something, it says that onSearch is not a function.

```
const { SearchBar, ClearSearchButton } = Search;
const Columnlist = props => {
  //add filterFactory into bootstrap table
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <h1 className="h2">Variables</h1>
      <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
      <ClearSearchButton />
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="id"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        striped
        hover
        condensed
        search
        noDataIndication="No Variable Meets Search Requirements"
        pagination={paginationFactory()}
        filter={filterFactory()}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Columnlist;
```

Comment: Did you put the toolkit provider ? you can check the storybook if you need something : https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Table%20Search&selectedStory=Basic%20Search%20Table&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to wrap your return component in the `<ToolkitProvider />` higher-order component like so?

```
return (
    <ToolkitProvider
        keyField="id"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        search
    >
        {
            (props) => (
                <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                <h1 className="h2">Variables</h1>
                    <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />

        ......

    </ToolkitProvider>
);
```